# Why bluring all circle isn`t only stroke of circle

Tags: javascript

context.filter = "blur(2px)";
Why this ^ element blur all circle space not only edges
I want to make circles blur on edges to look like blured street lights
i fetch stroke in
`if (stroke) { context.lineWidth = 1; context.strokeStyle = stroke; context.stroke();}`
and set the value in function invoke
`createCircle(x + Math.random() * 30 + 10, y - Math.random() * 50, (context.filter = "blur(2px)"));`
EDIT: I want to blur only the edges of cirlce not all space(fill) to look like street light
EDIT::: ATTACH FULL CODE

```js
let Drawing = false;

const fireworks = document.querySelector(".fireworks");
const context = fireworks.getContext("2d");

let x;
let y;
let numberCircles = 5;
const colors = ["#780000", "#c1121f", "#fdf0d5", "#003049", "#669bbc"];

//function seting window Size
function windowSize() {
    fireworks.width = window.innerWidth * 2;
    fireworks.height = window.innerHeight * 2;
    fireworks.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
    fireworks.style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
    context.scale(2, 2);
    // console.log("windowSize");
}

//create circle
function createCircle(x, y, stroke) {
    context.beginPath();
    radius = Math.random() * 5 + 3;
    let fill = colors[Math.round(Math.random() * colors.length - 1)];
    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

    if (fill) {
        context.fillStyle = fill;
        context.fill();
    }
    if (stroke) {
        context.lineWidth = 1;
        context.strokeStyle = stroke;
        context.stroke();
    }
}
//make circle spray DEPEND on  angle
function sprayCircle() {
    for (i = 0; i < numberCircles; i++) {
        let los = Math.round(Math.random() * 3);
        switch (los) {
            case 0:
                createCircle(x + Math.random() * 30 + 10, y + Math.random() * 50, (context.filter = "blur(2px)"));
                break;
            case 1:
                createCircle(x + Math.random() * 30 + 10, y - Math.random() * 50, (context.filter = "blur(2px)"));
                break;
            case 2:
                createCircle(x - Math.random() * 5, y - Math.random() * 5);
                break;
        }
    }
}

//mouse follow
fireworks.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
    Drawing = true;
});

fireworks.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
    if (Drawing === true) {
        sprayCircle();
        x = e.offsetX;
        y = e.offsetY;
    }
});
window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
    if (Drawing === true) {
        Drawing = false;
    }
});
//end

windowSize();
window.addEventListener("resize", windowSize, false);
```

```html
    <canvas class="fireworks" width="560" height="868"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I saw SyntaxError when I tried to run the code snippet.

Comment: yea becouse i trim the code like  bot said  couse i have more wornings and try to avoid ban

Comment: Try now sholud work